VBA Excel FileDialogFilePicker opens twice
I have the FilePicker for choosing my Excel file. Unfortunately with the following code:
 Option Explicit

 Sub Select_form()
 Dim FilePicker As FileDialog
 Dim mypath As String

 Dim formwb As Workbook

 Set FilePicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

 With FilePicker
    .Title = "Please select the hazard form"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .ButtonName = "Confirm selection"
        If .Show = -1 Then
        mypath = .SelectedItems(1)
        Else
        End
    End If
 End With

 Set formwb = openDataFile
 Debug.Print formwb.Name


 End Sub


 Function openDataFile() As Workbook

'
Dim wb            As Workbook
Dim filename      As String
Dim fd            As FileDialog
 Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
 fd.AllowMultiSelect = False
 fd.Title = "Select the file to extract data"

 ' Optional properties: Add filters
 fd.Filters.Clear
 fd.Filters.Add "Excel files", "*.xls*" ' show Excel file extensions only

 ' means success opening the FileDialog
 If fd.Show = -1 Then
 filename = fd.SelectedItems(1)
 End If

 ' error handling if the user didn't select any file
 If filename = "" Then
 MsgBox "No Excel file was selected !", vbExclamation, "Warning"
 End
 End If

 Set openDataFile = Workbooks.Open(filename)

 End Function

The filedialog opens twice.
I tried these hints:
https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/how-to-use-multiple-directories-using-vba.922514/
https://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/959014-file-dialog-runs-twice
but with no results

What’s triggering it?

I have the function you see in the code, but the file dialog opens twice. I mean after the selection of the Excel file it opens again.

Yes but how is it triggered? How do you invoke the opening of the dialog? A button? A timer? Some other event?

You are showing the dialog in Sub Select_Form. That Sub also calls Function openDataFile() which also shows the dialog. Why are you surprised that it is shown twice when you are calling twice?

In the calling procedure (Select_form) Just use Dim formwb As Workbook: Set formwb = openDataFile: If formwb Is Nothing Then Exit Sub: Debug.Print formwb.Name.

Doesn't work unfortunately

What does that mean? Is there an error (which one, which line)?

No error at all. Situation simply like this:
I am pressing the button - the code executes well
The file dialog opens for the first time - I am picking up the excel file for load.

Open File Using the FileDialog Object
Sub Select_form()
    
    Dim formwb As Workbook: Set formwb = OpenExcelFile
    If formwb Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    ' Continue using 'formwb' e.g.:
    MsgBox "Just opened workbook """ & formwb.Name & """ located in """ _
        & formwb.Path & """.", vbInformation
    
End Sub

Function OpenExcelFile() As Workbook
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Open Excel File"
    Dim ErrorMsgString As String
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    Dim FilePath As String
    
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Title = "Select the file to extract data"
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "Excel files", "*.xls*"
        If .Show = -1 Then FilePath = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
    
    If Len(FilePath) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Dialog canceled!", vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
    Else
        Set OpenExcelFile = Workbooks.Open(FilePath)
    End If
    
    Exit Function
    
ProcExit:
    On Error Resume Next
        MsgBox ErrorMsgString, vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Function
ClearError:
    ErrorMsgString = "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & vbLf & vbLf _
        & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Function

